# ERROR Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-svg

I want to use svg file in my React native App, for that i have follow the documentation of **react-native-svg** package and try to implement manual linking way to use svg images.But I have got the error of **Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.** Please suggest the Solution.

code

```
import React from 'react';
import UserImg from './assets/vcraft_logo.svg';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Icon</Text>
        <UserImg width={120} height={40} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `<img src={UserImg} />`